# How to use mixins from external stylesheet in Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.0's `paper-card` element got an update today which appears to have added a new mixin, although it is not documented on the site yet: `--paper-card-background-color`

In the same step, it appears that the Polymer developers also set the default background color to `--primary-background-color` which is not the color I'd like my paper-cards to be...

So, I set about trying to set the background color back to white from an external stylesheet. However, it doesn't appear to be working at all. I've tried many different methods, but I must be missing something. Does anybody know how to do this? The official Polymer docs cover this topic from the perspective of creating custom elements, but I am only trying to style a pre-existing one using the provided mixin hooks.

I've tried these so far, but none of them were able to override the default background color. Note that these were tried separately, not all at the same time ;)

```
:root { --paper-card-background-color:#ffffff; }
:root { --paper-card: { background-color:#ffffff; }
:root { --paper-card { background-color:#ffffff; }
--paper-card: { --paper-card-background-color:#ffffff; }
--paper-card { --paper-card-background-color:#ffffff; }
--paper-card { background-color:#ffffff; }
--paper-card: { background-color:#ffffff; }
paper-card { background-color:#ffffff; }
paper-card { --paper-card-background-color:#ffffff; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. If anyone else is having similar problems, here are the basics:

1. For Polymer specific mixin styles, make a separate stylesheet in a .html file
2. Wrap the contents of your new .html stylesheet in `<style is="custom-style"></style>` tags.
3. Write your styles inbetween your style tags (example below)
4. Import the stylesheet into your app with something like this: `<link rel="import" href="../styles/custom-styles.html">`

Here is what my stylesheet ended up looking like:

**custom-styles.html**

```
<style is="custom-styles">
:root { 
  --paper-card: { background-color: #ffffff; }
}
</style>
```

I couldn't get `--paper-card-background-color` working directly, but maybe it isn't finished yet - that could explain the missing documentation.